# php firebase authenication tokens

Tags: php, authentication, firebase, firebase-security

ive tried to authenticate to restrict access but i cant get it to work ive tried with both helper libs and using just curl but it does not work for me.  i get full access no matter what i use in the token for 'uiqd'.

here is the code

```
$url1 = 'https://***.firebaseio.com/';
$secret = '***';
$user = array( 'v' => 0, 'iat' => time(), 'd' => array('uidq' => 'qq'));
$token = JWT::encode($user, $secret);
$testurl =$url1. 'test.json?auth='.$token;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $testurl
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
return $response;
```

rules

either

```
"test": {".read": auth.uidq !== 'qq'}
```

or

```
"test": {".read":  false}
```

none work.  I still get access to the data. These rules are just for testing purposes.

can someone put a working example with the php script and the security rules online so i test it working to restrict and allow access. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the official firebase php generator -- works great
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-php